# Do we say "After 7th grade" or "After THE 7th grade"

Tags: definite-articles, prepositional-phrases

I would like to ask if we say "After 7th grade" or "After THE 7th grade"

Comment: We say both. They mean the same thing.

Comment: I would expect *after 7th grade* to be more common in my region (Texas/South USA). I can't back this up with Ngrams, but I highly question the accuracy or even relevance of Ngrams when talking about what people **say**.

Answer (score 1):

Both are used, but "After **the** 7th grade" is slightly more common.

Source: [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=after+7th+grade%2Cafter+the+7th+grade&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cafter%207th%20grade%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cafter%20the%207th%20grade%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: I am unconvinced ngrams accurately represent **speech** patterns.

Comment: @CarSmack I concur.